# Ubuntu 10.04 will not respond to keyboard entry of apache ssl passphrase

Tags: keyboard, apache2, ssl

I have a ubuntu machine that will not respond to keyboard entry of a apache ssl passphrase.  It's like the keyboard is not responding at all.  Is there a way I can disable this service from starting during the boot process? How can I use a live cd to disable this pass phrase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've just come out of such a scenario and what's worse, it took place on a virtual (ESXi 4) client facing server. Here's what I did to get things back up and running for those of you with similar problems.  I didn't find much on the net about this so I hope this helps.

First, I popped in and booted from a live CD.  From the terminal, I listed all available drives.

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

After identifying the correct hard disk - in this case sda1, I mounted it.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/drive1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/drive1
```

At this point, I dug into apache's configs and I figured the quickest/best thing to do would be to turn the SSL engine off temporarily.

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
```

Your config may be different.  In the past, I've seen this line in other files such as apache.conf and ports.conf.  Look for the section below, and change 'on' to 'off'.

```
#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine off
```

After saving, ejecting the disc and restarting, I was able to get back onto the server.  I repeated the above step to turn SSL back on.

This is a confirmed bug that has been resolved.  Solution would be to upgrade apache to at least version 2.2.16-4 [according to this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/582963).